# What is the proper usage of CollectionView(Source) in MVVM pattern?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, collectionviewsource

I'm trying to be as strict as possible when designing MVVM applications in terms of separating layers. In particular, I do my best to never leak anything platform-related to my viewmodels, and by platform I mean OS-related stuff, but also WPF-related stuff. Even though I barely ever reuse my viewmodels for different platforms, I try to keep them reusable as a good practice.

Some time ago I stumbled upon problem of sorting, grouping and filtering collections. The obvious solution for that in WPF is `CollectionViewSource`. But then things start to get complicated.

First, the facts:

- `ObservableCollection` lies in `System.ComponentModel`, so we may treat it as non-platform (safe to use inside viewmodel).
- `CollectionViewSource` resides in `PresentationFramework` assembly, so i treat this class as WPF-native, so platform and thus unusable in viewmodels.
- `CollectionView` also resides in `PresentationFramework`, so I cannot use it in viewmodel either
- `ICollectionView` (which obviously `CollectionView` implements) in turn resides in `System.ComponentModel` (`WindowsBase`), so it seems to be non-platform.

I always struggled, how to properly implement the whole `CollectionViewSource`-thing. Usually I:

- Place `CollectionViewSource` in window/control resources and bind its `Source` to viewmodel's property
- Bind list control's `ItemsSource` property to the `CollectionViewSource` by the kind-of weird binding: `ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvsSource}}"`
- Implement filtering and sorting in the window/control, only consulting viewmodel when needed (e.g. getting filter string from it)

This seems kind of sketchy to me though.

The problem is generally, *is sorting, filtering and grouping considered part of presentation or business logic*?

Theoretically, presentation. But then one may quickly realize, that even though filtering a collection is related to presentation, knowing *how* to filter it boils down to business logic (-> viewmodel).

Since though `ICollectionView` seems to be platform-free, I consider the following scenario:

- Place `CollectionViewSource` in resources as earlier
- Bind `ItemsSource` the same way as earlier, but then
- Extract `ICollectionView` from `CollectionViewSource` in the view (window/control) and pass it into the viewmodel. This will give viewmodel full control over sorting, filtering, selecting etc.

Is it a proper way of using `CollectionViewSource`? Or am I still getting things wrong and it should be solved yet in another way? Is there any documentation which shows, how to properly use `CollectionViewSource` according to MVVM requirements? (in terms: not instantiating it inside viewmodel)?

Comment: MVVM ist not about class level dependencies. MVVM is also not about isolating the view model from platform specific library code. It's only about decoupling the view from the business logic. It works primarily at application level. For example,  if CollectionView depends on on a "platform" class then you would have to build and deliver the PresentationFramework assembly too. Which means in your world CollectionView is also taboo. Namespaces are a different concept. They are not meant to implement any design pattern but to resolve ambiguity in the first place.

Comment: If you want to create  cross platform code then simply don't reference the .NET OS library (configure your project to target the proper .NET platform i.e. set the target framework accordingly). What you are doing is not a requirement that the MVVM design pattern describes. Defining an instance of CollectionViewSource in a view model class can never violate the MVVM design pattern. But referencing an instance that lives in the view component from the view model component does, because at component level this would require the view model to reference the view which is not allowed.

Comment: Also regarding "platform free": when you have a view model then you are always coupled to a particular platform. That's the nature of MVVM. The point is that the view model is the integral part of this pattern and it is designed to be used by the view. And view is always platform specific - in your case the chosen platform is WPF. Platform agnostic refers to reusable libraries that you want to be able to use platform independent. This more likely applies to your business domain. In your case you really over complicate your life if want to ban WPF specific libraries from your WPF application.

Comment: The System.Windows.Data namespace contains useful classes like BindingOperations or CollectionView your view model very likely needs in order to prepare data for presentation in the view. There is no benefit in designing the view model cross-platform compatible. When you decide to use a framework (e.g., WPF)  then this framework dictates the types you have to use. Not the framework client. You can always define the CollectionViewSource in your view (even in XAML) if this helps. Controls that support sorting and filtering raise related events you can handle to implement your filtering  logic.

Comment: [How to: Filter Data in a View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-filter-data-in-a-view?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netdesktop-7.0) shows how to handle the CollectionViewSource.Filter event to define the filtering logic. If you define the CollectionViewSource in your view you can implement the event handler and the complete filter logic in the view too. Same applies to sorting. Usually the control handles such operations. For example the DataGrid sorts by clicking a column header. So is possible to not filter and sort in the view model.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's important to try to avoid using Presentation Framework classes inside your ViewModel cause MVVM frameworks come and goes away all the time.
Imagine if you have your VM's isolated on a pure .NET 7 project and on top of it you have another WPF project that references the first project to use these ViewModels as the DataContext of it's views.
Then a few years later another MVVM based UI framework like UWP appears on the market. All you have to to it's to create a UWP on that solution and re-use your VM's on the brand new UWP project. Then a few months later another cool MVVM based UI framework appears once again like WinUI 3. The same will apply.

Other scenario, let suppose you have a native desktop Windows app (It could be WPF, UWP or WinUI) and then you decide make it run on mobile using MAUI, Avalonia or UNO. If you have all of your ViewModels decoupled from any specific UI framework you can put these VM's on a pure .NET Standard / .NET 6,7,8 project, and then use these same VM's on all of your UI specific projects.

So IMO despite of being hard to make your VM's UI-Framework agnostic, it should make your code more reusable and that should pay the bill in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is generally, is sorting, filtering and grouping considered part of presentation or business logic?

The purpose of layering is better maintainability through minimal interfaces. So, imho, "just give me the data, I'll present it" is the minimal interface. But reality is harsh, and so you might need to e.g. to filter your data in backend due to performance reasons. But this makes your interface more complex, so it's a compromise.
I would almost always put grouping and sorting into the presentation category, because you can easily imagine very different views tailored to different user roles with different requirements about sorting and grouping.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why I would not usually use collectionview or collectionviewsource for filtering and sorting.

Two outweigh most of them though:

**Collectionview filtering and sorting is inefficient.**

That might not matter, depends on your data.

If you have just a few hundred rows you're possibly going to deal with then it doesn't matter if it's slow.

**There is often too much data.**

If you have thousands of transactions a second you're obviously not going to pull that table across onto the client and then start thinking about filtering it. It's not going to even get there.

You don't need very many rows before it becomes advisable to do that filtering on the server. When you have substantial amounts of data ( and most systems I have worked on do ) you need to think about paging as well.  That means you need to sort on the server as well.

I also do not like sorting on the UI so much.

It's expensive to test UI based logic. I prefer minimal code in the UI. This BTW is the reason to encapsulate any UI code you have for re-use in behaviours. This is why you don't want much code in your code behind.

I would not be too concerned about viewmodel libraries necessitating "view" dll.
With two caveats:
Unless

a) You're developing with MAUI or some such re-usability in mind

OR

b) Your automated test vm is linux.

Otherwise it's academic what windows only dll are required. The wpf app will definitely require those when delivered.